# PHP, disabling the POST on refresh & displaying message

Tags: php, forms, session, post, http-headers

I have a form with this code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

So basically, whenever a visitor click on Submit, the page refresh and I do my operations. Everything works perfectly fine, however it seems like I must choose between disabling the re-post on refresh by doing this:

```
header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
```

OR display me error & success message, but if I do so, if the visitor refresh the page it resubmit.

I read online about two options to fix this issue:

- Redirect to another page (can't take this route as it would break the flow of the visit)
- Store my message array in a SESSION variable (My problem here is that the SESSION would end up staying for too long, if the user refresh or revisit the page the message array needs to be empty...)

So, are there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: unset($_POST); after submit, then reset the form after submit

Comment: @SRK uh, no. the browser will still re-submit if you refresh

Comment: You pretty much need to use one of those two solutions you mention. Redirect to another page, or refresh the page so it is no longer a POST operation. Note that if you do go with the session route, you can easily delete the session data after you have processed it so that it can't be re-used.

Comment: redirect to a confirmation page.

Comment: What's wrong with resubmitting on refreshing?

Comment: Just use $_GET instead of $_POST and it won't resubmit on refresh.

Comment: The user is submitting images each time, so these images are recreated each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a uniqe ticket like a timestamp for ex. an put it as an additional parameter to your form. Now you can store the processed requests in a session or cookie. A simple example:

client:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="requestTicket" value="<?php echo time(); ?>" />
    ...
```

server:

```
if(!array_key_exists("rt", $_SESSION))
    $_SESSION["rt"] = array();

if(!array_key_exists($_REQUEST["requestTicket"], $_SESSION["rt"])) {
    //do the job
    //...

    $_SESSION["rt"][$_REQUEST["requestTicket"]] = true;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, do you have an example of how to do this at hand ? I am not sure how this would disable the refresh issue...

Comment: @Dacramash i added a simple example.

Comment: Seems to be working, however I do not need the header("Location:") anymore right ?

Comment: @Dacramash correct, only one of this solutions is needed to solve this.

Comment: So after all of this, seems like I need to use a header to force refresh (our images are on a CDN, I launch the code to purge the cache but need to force the refresh)... Do you know if there would be some way to mix your fix with a header somehow ?

Comment: @Dacramash just put your header function at the end.

Comment: Hm, I tried to put it at the end however now it shows my error/success message briefly, then refresh the page and I lose em. This is the refresh code that Im using:             header("Refresh:0;url=http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");